# Using VBA to insert a pic into a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I created a PPT template to insert a picture(pic is under same folder as PPT file), but it shows the error message:

> run-time error '-2147024809'(80070057)': the specified file was not found.

The error has shown up when we turned to office 365, and the codes are blow:

```
Sub Eclipse12_5()
    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:="125mg.png", _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=165, Top:=70).Select

    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:="text.png", _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=625, Top:=20).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You likely need to tell the code where to look for the file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture

Comment: You only have the file name. You need to include the complete path.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply. The pic file and the ppt are under same folder. I am new to VBA, could you please tell me which code I should use to indicate the 'current folder'. The template will be used by different users, so the folder name wont be the same